# Clarify the meaning of APIs

Tags: api, google-maps, youtube

**An application-programming interface (API) is a set of programming instructions and standards for accessing a Web-based software application.** Could someone explain to me in case of **Google maps** or **Youtube** which is the `API` and which is the `software application`? Are both visible to us and how? I know there are tons of articles out there, however I cannot clarify the above. APIs are like the waiters that transfer data among different machines. Okay, which exactly is the Google maps API and how do we call/use it? And which is the Google maps software application which is accessed by the API? When we write for example http://maps.google.co.uk/ do we call the API? My query may seem silly but I cannot find a good answer for that.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Don't stress too much on these terms. Knowing that API is an exposed interface of a software application which is running in house should be more than enough for you to take the next step. I suggest you to try spring boot web service tutorial to get a basic idea of an API https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An application-programming interface (API) is a set of programming
>   instructions and standards for accessing a Web-based software
>   application.

Firstly, an API is not just for web-based software. Even your computer's OS provides APIs for hardware and software installed in the box.

For your question, an API is a method (code instructions) to connect **your application** to the features of another system. Allowing your application to use thay system's features as provided via the API.

> Could someone explain to me in case of Google maps or Youtube which is
>   the **API** and which is the **software application**?

In the case of Youtube... Let's say you are making some Android video player app that you also want to be able to playback Youtube videos within that app. The **software application** is your own Android player code and to access the Youtube data you would use **[Youtube's Android API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)**.

An example of using the API is this module : **[YouTubePlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)** which as you can see provide API commands like `loadVideo(String videoId, int timeMillis)`. Where `videoId` is the Youtube ID and `timeMillis` is the desired start time within the video).

> When we write for example http://maps.google.co.uk/ how do we call the
>   API?

That's not how you would call the API. You must first visit the documentation of the API to see how it's expected to call features within your own app.

Google Maps : **[`https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)**

Let's assume now you're coding a Javascript app, you can see the commands **[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)** as a startng point. There is also an **[example page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)** showing code & result.

Answer (score 1):

Simple terms:

API = the waiter

Application Software = the chef

You order from the waiter. The waiter brings it to the chef. The chef prepares the food. The waiter then brings you your food. Then you figure out what to do with the food; eat it, take it home, throw it on the floor, let your dog eat it, give it the homeless, etc...

A website, app, etc... would send an API request (your order with the waiter) to Google Maps (the chef). If your API request is valid, Google Maps will send back an response (your cooked food with the waiter). Then the website or app takes the returned data and displays it in their custom way to you.

In the case of Google Maps, apps like Yelp and others use Google Maps' API to request specific data; routes, addresses, etc… and then they display it on their app.

To make an API request/call you have access to use the API, format it correctly, and figure out what to do when Google sends a response back : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

> API is a set of functions and procedures that allow the creation of applications which access the features or data of an operating system, application, or other service.

An API is like building block for your application. Multiple API's can exchange data without knowing the other's implementation. In a good design pattern , we should design API's for different independent tasks and then merge them.

- [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

This is the google maps API which a developer can use to develop his own piece of software.

Whenever we use any software and it's different features, we might be using their API's without generally knowing of them.

A software application is always visible to us, but an API is visible only if the developer wants to expose it for community use.

**EDIT**

[Using Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)
 This link has the documentation and examples on how to use the google maps API using javascript.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you use software, web applications included, you are in most cases using a wrapped API.  Software developers took the time to take a raw back end API which executes commands on the system, and made these endpoints easy to use for a specific user in an intended universe of discourse, or domain.  End users do not have direct access to everything the API has to offer all at once, so it is not "available" in the same sense that it is available to the developers, but it is available in another sense because they are using the API to execute commands on the system by virtue of the **A**pplication that was **P**rogrammed with that **I**nterface existing and working.

The Google Maps API is used to integrate the power of Google Maps into almost any application.  It provides facilities for customization and much more.  When you use the Google Maps webapp, it is, to my knowledge, built using many components of the Google Maps API, as are the Google Maps apps for any other platform, such as Android.  Does this mean you as a user are using the API?  Only through the application; the application talks to the API for you.

Answer (score 0):

“An application programming interface (API) is a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software applications. An API expresses a software component in terms of its operations, inputs, outputs, and underlying types. An API defines functionalities that are independent of their respective implementations, which allows definitions and implementations to vary without compromising each other. A good API makes it easier to develop a program by providing all the building blocks.

APIs often come in the form of a library that includes specifications for routines, data structures, object classes, and variables. In other cases, notably SOAP and REST services, an API is simply a specification of remote calls exposed to the API consumers.

An API specification can take many forms, including an International Standard, such as POSIX, vendor documentation, such as the Microsoft Windows API, or the libraries of a programming language, e.g., the Standard Template Library in C++ or the Java APIs.

An API differs from an application binary interface (ABI) in that an API is source code-based while an ABI is a binary interface. For instance POSIX is an API, while the Linux Standard Base provides an ABI”.

To speak plainly, an API is the messenger that runs and delivers your request to the provider you’re requesting it from, and then delivers the response back to you.

To give you a familiar example, think of an API as a waiter in a restaurant.

Imagine you’re sitting at the table with a menu of choices to order from, and the kitchen is the provider who will fulfill your order.

What’s missing is the critical link to communicate your order to the kitchen and deliver your food back to your table.

That’s where the waiter (or API) comes in. ”AHEM”

The waiter takes your order, delivers it to the kitchen, and then delivers the food (or response) back to you. (Hopefully without letting your order crash if designed correctly)

Now that we’ve whetted your appetite, let’s apply this to a real API example. In keeping with our theme, let’s book a flight to a culinary capital – Paris.

You’re probably familiar with the process of searching for airline flights online. Just like at a restaurant, you have a menu of options to choose from ( a dropdown menu in this case). You choose a departure city and date, a return city and date, cabin class, and other variables (like meal or seating, baggage or pet requests)

In order to book your flight, you interact with the airline’s website to access the airline’s database to see if any seats are available on those dates, and what the cost might be based on certain variables.

But, what if you are not using the airline’s website, which has direct access to the information? What if you are using online travel service that aggregates information from many different airlines? Just like a human interacts with the airline’s website to get that information, an application interacts with the airline’s API.

The API is the interface that, like your helpful waiter, runs and and delivers the data from that online travel service to the airline’s systems over the Internet.

It also then takes the airline’s response to your request and delivers right back to the online travel service .

And through each step of the process it facilitates that interaction between the travel service and the airline’s systems - from seat selection to payment and booking.

So now you can see that it’s APIs that make it possible for us all to use travel sites. They interface with with airlines’ APIs to gather information in order to present options back to us

The same goes for all interactions between applications, data and devices - they all have API’s that allow computers to operate them, and that's what ultimately creates connectivity.

API’s provide a standard way of accessing any application, data or device whether it is shopping from your phone, or accessing cloud applications at work.

So, whenever you think of an API, just think of it as your waiter running back and forth between applications, databases and devices to deliver data and create the connectivity that puts the world at our fingertips. And whenever you think of creating an API,

--MuleSoft